# PHP class visibility

Tags: php, class, class-design

I am learning about PHP classes. I do have a bit of a C++ under my belt.

My goal here is to instantiate classes when a user loads my site and be able to use those classes while the users is on the site and then destroy.

Are there global classes in PHP? Where I could instantiate a class and have every users that hits my site get the values set in that class? Like page titles, default values, application defaults, default MySQL queries, etc?

I am not using a framework at this time, rather trying to learn myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some global classes within the [SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php).

However, class instances do not live longer than a single request, you have to instantiate/recreate them for every request.

Hope this helps...